# Angular $injector:unpr with uibModal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

The code is almost straight from the ui-bootstrap tutorial. I have a button on my homepage with an ng-click for opening the modal window, but the error I receive in dev tools is :

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- modalController`

and each click after this adds a `modalController` to the error message, like

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- modalController <- modalController`

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- modalController <- modalController <- modalController`

home.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('homeCtrl', ['$q', '$state', '$timeout', '$scope', '$http', '$filter',
  '$uibModal', function($q, $state, $timeout, $scope, $http, $filter, $uibModal){

$scope.open = function (size){
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
    templateUrl: 'app/main/searchModal.html',
    controller: 'modalController',
    size: size,
    resolve: {
      items: function () {
        return $scope.items;
      }
    }
  });

  modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
  });
};
...
```

modalcontroller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
  $uibModalInstance.close();
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on our (the library's) end.  When we released 0.14.0 and added all the `uib` prefixes, we missed adding it to `modalInstance`.  The issue was fixed in 0.14.3.

To fix this issue in 0.14.0 - 0.14.2 simply use `$modalInstance` instead and note that when you upgrade to 1.0, you'll need to change to `$uibModalInstance` or the code will barf again.

[Here's a link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4638) to the relevant issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks correct.  Another thing to check is to make sure the angular-ui-bootstrap library is getting injected in your application dependencies:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

And that you are using the version of angular-ui-bootstrap that has the prefix changes.  Version 0.14.0 introduced the 'uib' prefixes, Version 1.0.0 removed support for un-prefixed components.  Prior to version 0.14.0 the $uibModalInstance was $modalInstance.

Comment: `angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'smart-table',
  'nvd3',
  'angucomplete-alt'
])` are my dependencies. I'm using Angular 1.4.7 and 0.14.0 ui-bootstrap, so I don't see any issue there. The fact that each click adds another `modalController` is what is really throwing me off.